# MySQL not starting when shut down with mysqladmin

Tags: mysql, debian

MySQL server 5.5 fails to start when I use the mysqladmin shutdown command to stop the server. The only option to start MySQL server is to reboot the machine.

Is there is any option so that I can start MySQL server normally with `/etc/init.d/mysql start`?

I am using Debian 8 jessie.

Comment: please share mysql log.